# Convert an instance of xgboost.Booster into a model that implements the scikit-learn API

Tags: scikit-learn, save, xgboost, mlflow, xgbclassifier

I am trying to use `mlflow` to save a model and then load it later to make predictions.

I'm using a `xgboost.XGBRegressor` model and its sklearn functions `.predict()` and `.predict_proba()` to make predictions but it turns out that `mlflow` doesn't support models that implements the sklearn API, so when loading the model later from mlflow, mlflow returns an instance of `xgboost.Booster`, and it doesn't implements the `.predict()` or `.predict_proba()` functions.

Is there a way to convert a `xgboost.Booster` back into a `xgboost.sklearn.XGBRegressor` object that implements the sklearn API functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping up your model in custom class, logging and loading it using `mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel`?
I put up a simple example and upon loading back the model it correctly shows `<class 'xgboost.sklearn.XGBRegressor'>` as a type.

Example:

```
import xgboost as xgb
xg_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(...)

class CustomModel(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def __init__(self, xgbRegressor):
        self.xgbRegressor = xgbRegressor

    def predict(self, context, input_data):
        print(type(self.xgbRegressor))
        
        return self.xgbRegressor.predict(input_data)

# Log model to local directory
with mlflow.start_run():
     custom_model = CustomModel(xg_reg)
     mlflow.pyfunc.log_model("custome_model", python_model=custom_model)


# Load model back
from mlflow.pyfunc import load_model
model = load_model("/mlruns/0/../artifacts/custome_model")
model.predict(X_test)
```

Output:

```
<class 'xgboost.sklearn.XGBRegressor'>
[ 9.107417 ]
```

Comment: I believe this requires using pickle for the `CustomModel` class which isn't very portable

Answer (score 0):

I have a xgboost.core.Booster object and it can make return probability calculations as follows your_Booster_model_object.predict(your_xgboost_dmatrix_dataset).